# Chrome extension message passing from background script to content script error: receiving end doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script, message-passing

I'm working on a chrome extension currently, and I keep getting this error:

Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

I'm trying to pass a message from my background script to my content script. The background script fetches the url of the current tab, and I'm trying to pass that URL to my content script. I've found a few different solutions to this error, but none of them are working for me. From what I understand, it has something to do with the content script not being loaded when the background script tries to send the message, though I've tried some workarounds for that and nothing has worked for me. This is my code:

Background script:

```
//use a query to get the current URL of the tab
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        lastFocusedWindow: true
    }, function(tabs){
        var currentTab = tabs[0];
        var currentUrl = currentTab.url;
        //send a message from background script to content script
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            const port = chrome.tabs.connect(tabs[0].id);
            port.postMessage({url: currentUrl});
            port.onMessage.addListener(function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    }
    );
```

Content Script:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port){
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg){
    if(msg.url.includes("amazon")){
        console.log("You are on amazon.com");
    }
    port.postMessage("This is my response!");
  });
});
```

Here is my manifest as well:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "First Browser Extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Add a better description later.",
    "page_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "BrowserExtension",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "background":{
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches": ["https://www.amazon.com/*"],
            "js":  ["content.js"] 
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "icons": {"48": "icon.png"} 
}
```

I can't figure out what's going wrong. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: updated code

Background

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true //changed lastFocusedWindow to currentWindow
}, function(tabs){
    var currentTab = tabs[0];
    var currentUrl = currentTab.url;
    console.log(currentUrl);
    //----------NEW CODE---------------------------
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
      function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.contentScriptQuery === "getURL") {
          sendResponse({url: currentUrl});
          return true;  // Will respond asynchronously.
        }
      });
}
);
```

Content

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {contentScriptQuery: "getURL"},
    function(urlFromBackground){
        console.log(urlFromBackground.url);
   }
);
```

Comment: The posted code doesn't tell us how and when this code runs, which is the root of the observed problem. Show your manifest.json and a more complete fragment of code in the background script because currently the code doesn't make sense as it's not inside an event listener and it appears to make a frequent mistake of using chrome.tabs.query instead of using the event's `tab` or `tabId` parameter so you may be trying to connect to an empty new tab that has chrome://newtab URL and thus cannot have a content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm I added my manifest and little bit about what the extension is doing. I'm using the background script to fetch the URL of the current tab and passing it to the content script. What should I use instead of chrome.tabs.query? I thought that is what I needed to do in order to pass a message to a content script.

Comment: Ah, then remove all those query() and use simple messaging as [shown in the CORB explainer](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches#TOC-2.-Avoid-Cross-Origin-Fetches-in-Content-Scripts).

Comment: @wOxxOm Ahh thank you so much! That fixed the problem! Now, however, I'm realizing that the extension is not returning the url of the page I am on, as it should, but rather the page that I am reloading the extension on (chrome://extensions or chrome://extensions/errors . . .). Does this have something to do with the message passing being asynchronous? Or something to do with my original tabs query? I'll add updated code to question.

Comment: Like I said, remove all calls to chrome.tabs.query(). You don't need it. Your content script already knows the URL of its page: `location.href`

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you!! That is so much simpler!